# Set different user access token expiration time per application

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have looked on internet, but I can't find out any solution, I think that is not possible. But that is very important support feature, different applications has it's own needs of expiration time. There any way to configure that on WSO2APIM?

Comment: Could you explain more your question ?

Comment: Yes of course, the default user application token expires with 3600 seconds, but, this configuration doesn't work to all applications needs, there  an application that needs expire token with less than 3600, are you understanding?

Comment: So your question is about expiry time? Title doesn't say so.

Comment: Yes I corrected that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found work arround for similar issue. I have used WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 integrated with WSO2 IS with SQL Server Database, You can give a try with this as well, it should work for you as well.

I have created API to update "[VALIDITY_PERIOD]" column value for "[IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN]" table in the associated database.

You can set any required expiry time in this table.

For more details, you can refer to below link:

https://bhajanmehtablog.wordpress.com/2017/02/01/playing-with-access-oauth-token-for-wso2-api-manager-or-wso2-is/

Please let me know if you (@kelber Rocha) have any other specific query regarding this same, your environment details will be helpful for further assistance, like which like of database you are using with API Manager and which version etc.

Comment: I understanding what you saying on your blog, but I need to manipulate validity_period every time that my users create a token, so, it looks very expensive to our setup, we are using sql server too. It is what you doing? Every token created by your users, you call an api to update validity period of token?

Comment: @KleberRocha: we have a default expiry time which will be applied on all APIs - if your is not happy with that time interval then as of now we have two solutions: (1) either use refresh token API (2) or use this custom API.